# How can i get object ID just after persist on database?

Tags: php, pdo, persistence

I'm using PHP PDO to persist in my database. So, just after persist an object i need to use this ID to use it at another query.

```
$stmt->execute();
$idObjectInserted = ?
```

The question is: Is there some way to get Object ID just after persist? I don't want to use any framework to do that, is there some way to do this task with native PHP code?

SOLVED BY VolkerK, Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [PDO::lastInsertId](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: Ho my gosh! It may solve my problem bro, i'll test, i'll be back as soon as i test it.